# Getting someone's Steam inventory

Tags: api, inventory, steam

I am making a website that needs to access the Steam inventory of the user. I found an API to get Team Fortress 2 inventory, Dota 2, CS:S, CS:GO and Portal 2. But I didn't find any API for getting Steam inventory.

Is it possible to access a user's Steam inventory?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

### New Endpoint

There is a new end point for fetching inventories as of December 2016. The old one listed below still works (for now). Both seem to be highly ratelimited.

The new inventory path is:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/<PROFILEID>/440/2?l=english&count=5000
```

With this new path, `l` is the language you want to receive data back in and `count` is the number of items to receive back at a time. The maximum is 5000.

You can paginate with this new end point too:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/<PROFILEID>/440/2?l=english&count=5000&start_assetid=468336866
```

This will pull the next 5000 items starting with assetid `468336866`.

The end point returns a large json object with the following structure:

```
{ 
    'assets': <list>,
    'descriptions': <list>,
    'total_inventory_count': integer,
    'success': 1/0,
    'rwgran': integer
}
```

I am not completely sure what `rwgran` is at this point.

The `assets` key, returns data that looks like this:

```
[{'amount': '1',
         'appid': '440',
         'assetid': '4985815666',
         'classid': '134',
         'contextid': '2',
         'instanceid': '0'},
        {'amount': '1',
         'appid': '440',
         'assetid': '4985815941',
         'classid': '22989188',
         'contextid': '2',
         'instanceid': '0'},
        ...
]
```

The `descriptions` key contains entries like this. Notice that this contains a lot for information than the old end point.

```
[{'actions': [{'link': 'http:\\/\\/wiki.teamfortress.com\\/scripts\\/itemredirect.php?id=241&lang=en_US',
                            'name': 'Item Wiki Page...'}],
               'appid': 440,
               'background_color': '3C352E',
               'classid': '134',
               'commodity': 0,
               'currency': 0,
               'descriptions': [{'type': 'text',
                                 'value': 'Is an enemy player questioning your skills, personal hygiene, and\\/or ancestry?\nUse these stylish firearms to challenge them to a duel!\nSee the Mann Co. Catalog for full details.'},
                                {'type': 'text', 'value': ' '},
                                {'color': '00a000',
                                 'type': 'text',
                                 'value': 'This is a limited use item.  Uses: 5'}],
               'icon_url': 'fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZULUrsm1j-9xgECbwgfYh_3vTRKhs_ZAfOeD-VOyo4z4clTizJqwQcpYOHnNDFmcweRVqQPCqVq91C-WCM26pFnB4PjofUWJ1uAGDnHsA',
               'icon_url_large': 'fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZULUrsm1j-9xgECbwgfYh_3vTRKhs_ZAfOeD-VOyo4z4clTizJqwQcpYOHnNDFmcweRVqQPCqVq91C-WCM26pFnB4PjofUWJ1uAGDnHsA',
               'instanceid': '0',
               'market_hash_name': 'Dueling Mini-Game',
               'market_marketable_restriction': 0,
               'market_name': 'Dueling Mini-Game',
               'market_tradable_restriction': 7,
               'marketable': 0,
               'name': 'Dueling Mini-Game',
               'name_color': '7D6D00',
               'tags': [{'category': 'Quality',
                         'color': '7D6D00',
                         'internal_name': 'Unique',
                         'localized_category_name': 'Quality',
                         'localized_tag_name': 'Unique'},
                        {'category': 'Type',
                         'internal_name': 'TF_UsableItem',
                         'localized_category_name': 'Type',
                         'localized_tag_name': 'Usable Item'},
                        {'category': 'Class',
                         'internal_name': 'Scout',
                         'localized_category_name': 'Class',
                         'localized_tag_name': 'Scout'},
                        {'category': 'Class',
                         'internal_name': 'Sniper',
                         'localized_category_name': 'Class',
                         'localized_tag_name': 'Sniper'},
                        {'category': 'Class',
                         'internal_name': 'Soldier',
                         'localized_category_name': 'Class',
                         'localized_tag_name': 'Soldier'},
                        {'category': 'Class',
                         'internal_name': 'Demoman',
                         'localized_category_name': 'Class',
                         'localized_tag_name': 'Demoman'},
                        {'category': 'Class',
                         'internal_name': 'Medic',
                         'localized_category_name': 'Class',
                         'localized_tag_name': 'Medic'},
                        {'category': 'Class',
                         'internal_name': 'Heavy',
                         'localized_category_name': 'Class',
                         'localized_tag_name': 'Heavy'},
                        {'category': 'Class',
                         'internal_name': 'Pyro',
                         'localized_category_name': 'Class',
                         'localized_tag_name': 'Pyro'},
                        {'category': 'Class',
                         'internal_name': 'Spy',
                         'localized_category_name': 'Class',
                         'localized_tag_name': 'Spy'},
                        {'category': 'Class',
                         'internal_name': 'Engineer',
                         'localized_category_name': 'Class',
                         'localized_tag_name': 'Engineer'}],
               'tradable': 1,
               'type': 'Level 5 Usable Item'},
      ...
]
```

As with the old method, the `assets` and `descriptions` are linked via the `classid` in both.

---

#### Old Endpoint

###### Update: This Endpoint is partialy unvailable since November 11th 2022, 00:00 CET

This endpoint will return `{ "success": false, "Error": "Unsupported request" }` in some regions (depends on account region). It's expected, that all regions will shut down this endpoint in the near future.

You can get some limited information if the target has their profile permissions set appropriately.

You can view the resulting `json` files by using either of these two links for beta (and gift, if appropriate permissions are set) inventories

`http://steamcommunity.com/id/<CUSTOMURL>/inventory/json/753/1`
`http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<PROFILEID>/inventory/json/753/1`

`CUSTOMURL` is the user friendly name the player has selected to use. This is changeable by the player at any time. If you are writing a web page, I assume you know how to get this piece of information, correct? `PROFILEID` is the 64Bit id that a player is given by Steam when you create the account. This is not changeable and it is returned by Steam when they log in using an OpenID implementation.

When using those URLs, there are a few possible responses. The first is if the user has their profile set to private.

`{"success":false,"Error":"This profile is private."}`

The second is a listing of "stuff" in the inventory

```
{
    "success":true,
    "rgInventory":
    {
        "1586670077416875609":
        {
            "id":"1586670077416875609",
            "classid":"149742033",
            "instanceid":"0",
            "amount":"1",
            "pos":1
        },
        "1586670077416875905":
        {
            "id":"1586670077416875905",
            "classid":"149742033",
            "instanceid":"0",
            "amount":"1",
            "pos":2
        },
        "1586670077416877092":
        {
            "id":"1586670077416877092",
            "classid":"149742033",
            "instanceid":"0",
            "amount":"1",
            "pos":3
        }
    },
    "rgCurrency":[],
    "rgDescriptions":
    {
        "149742033_0":
        {   "appid":"753",
        "classid":"149742033",
        "instanceid":"0",
        "icon_url":"ZyjGwQD4ogROtSm7KvtdP99kDHBEiKxKm3Gg7pMaBJyiPu4iS_PzF6QhOUdOwk-m0WhXYQ7X8AbNL6Hz1VxOnq4-8iBC5MlBuXMuElaaCrHQLww9T5S1Ecoqo_PYWg==",
        "icon_url_large":"a6FEz5nbBlvu8bGd1oDggdPtjn7dqwgVOzU4yG9huSKut2ws0tBXSARloWGyufIY3eHVb5f0VFltaznVKSfzK6amZz7FjFhcTTm6Maz860eOrMo937A=",
        "icon_drag_url":"",
        "name":"Steam Trading Card Beta",
        "market_name":"",
        "name_color":"",
        "background_color":"",
        "type":"Gift",
        "tradable":1,
        "marketable":0,
        "descriptions":[
            {"value":"Steam Trading Card Beta Access - Extra Copy"},
            {"value":"Grants early access to the Steam Trading Cards beta, game badges, and the new profile. Join the Steam Trading Cards Group and post your feedback in the Discussions area. Select \u201cAdd to my game library\u201d to activate."}
            ],
        "actions":[
            {"name":"View in store","link":"http:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/tradingcards"}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If the URL is for YOUR ID and you are logged into Steam, you can also see items that are listed as `Gift`. Otherwise, those are hidden by default.

Since this isn't an official API, there isn't much documentation about this particular schema. However, it appears that the items in `rgInventory` are linked to items in the `reDescriptions` by `classid`. Writing the parser is left as an exercise for the reader.

These shows the beta accesses.

If you are looking for trading card information, change the `1` in the above URLs to a `6`

`http://steamcommunity.com/id/<CUSTOMURL>/inventory/json/753/6`
`http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<PROFILEID>/inventory/json/753/6`

The schema layouts appear to be the same for these.

Comment: Just curious, how did you know this JSON data existed? How did you know about these links? Are they provided by Steam so users can manipulate their inventories?

Comment: @JustinLiang Lots of poking at the Steam Services. There may be documentation now, but when I wrote this, it was poking at the web UI and seeing what made it tick.

Comment: Wow, what a great find then :P

Comment: Hi, how do you handle Private Inventories? Is there no possible way to get it? I need to check the user's inventory if their items is Rare/Myth etc.

Comment: It is private. You don't get it, because they set it so that you can't.

Comment: Note that there's been a change in how inventories are displayed and now the given URL format only retrieves the first 2500 inventory items. It is necessary to append `?start=####` at the end of the URL to retrieve the next set of items. For example`?start=2500`. This is necessary to get complete data for very large inventories.

Comment: Hi guys. I need to take the photos of the items to list them. How I do that?
In some cases I see "generic_item" attribute in json that can show me more details about the item. Someone notice about this?

Comment: I tried viewing my inventory through this link and it doesn't show anything. I have 10 items in Steam inventory and 23 in Counter-Strike: Global Offensive but neither show anything. http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198213932720/inventory/json/753/1

Comment: It seems like `/2` (`http://steamcommunity.com/id/<CUSTOM_URL>/inventory/json/730/2/`) gives you their ordinary inventory contents.

Comment: Does anyone have a link to the docs for this? I want to find other params I can use. I cannot find it through google

Comment: @Andy did you ever figure out how to query for a specific, given item? Any combination of inputs about the item would be fine; so far my experiments to find it myself are all failing. For context, I'd like to be able to check an inventory for a specific item without having to paginate through 1000s of items. When I try using that start_assetid, the response doesn't actually include that asset id but the one after it. Frustratingly close to what I was looking for!

Comment: @Andy is there any endpoint to find a user's inventory contexts? [SteamApis.com has an unofficial API to do this](https://steamapis.com/docs/steam#profile). Wondering if this can be directly done.

Comment: Do anyone know how to avoid the ratelimits that keep crashing my code? I have made it so only inventory of a user is being cached for 30min but when I have 20 users every 30minute I am screwed. Any way to get out of this?

Comment: @OleDybedokken proxies

Answer (score 18):

Just to precise Andy's answer, the schema is:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<PROFILEID>/inventory/json/<APPID>/<CONTEXTID>
```

App ID identifies the game/application this inventory is related to : [here's the list](http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2).

Context ID filters the items, it varies from game to game.

Another thing: the items returned are uniquely identified by the classid-instanceid pair ([source](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API/IEconService)), so when you link them with their description, you should take both into account.

Comment: Copying my comment on Andy's post: Did you ever figure out how to query for a specific, given item? Any combination of inputs about the item would be fine. start_assetid is frustratingly close but it does not actually include in the response the assetId providing in the request, which is what i'd want.

Comment: @Jrs42 is there any way to know how many context ID's must be queried to get complete list of items? I found that value 2 works for most games but there could be more....

Comment: I don't know of a public API for accessing the list of contexts for a specific app and user (contexts are user specific but implementation is left to the app's developer). If you look at steamcommunity's website source, they simply inject a global variable named `g_rgAppContextData` into the page's body which lists available contexts.