# Steam trading cards API or achievements api

Tags: steam-web-api

Is there an API to get a user's steam trading cards?

I'm not very familiar with steam but it doesn't seem to be on this page.

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0001.29

There's an achievements API would that get me the trading cards info as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not an API for the trading cards (yet). You can, however, still find them. It does depend on the user's privacy settings though. I went into more detail on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393099/getting-someones-steam-inventory/17679641#17679641) and believe it will help you out.

Achievements can be pulled via the [GetPlayerAchievements](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerAchievements_.28v0001.29) API call using the following format:

`http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetPlayerAchievements/v0001/?appid=<APPID>&key=<APIKEY>&steamid=<PROFILEID>l=<LANG>`

`APPID` is the application ID the achievements are associated with (ie. Team Fortress 2 is 440)
`APIKEY` is the API key Valve assigned you
`PROFILEID` is the 64bit player ID give to you when you sign up on steam
`LANG` is the language you wish to return the descriptions in (this parameter is optional and not including it removes the `name` and `description` fields from the results). `en` is for English.

In the response is a listing of all of the achievements in the game.

```
{
    "apiname": "TF_MVM_PYRO_BOMB_RESET",
    "achieved": 0,
    "name": "Hard Reset",
    "description": "As a Pyro, reset the bomb 3 times in a single wave."
},
{
    "apiname": "TF_MVM_ENGINEER_ESCAPE_SENTRY_BUSTER",
    "achieved": 1,
    "name": "Real Steal",
    "description": "As an Engineer, escape with your sentry as a sentry buster is about to detonate."
},
```