# JSON of all Steam trading cards

Tags: json, steam, steam-web-api

Is a JSON file containing all Steam Trading Cards or all Steam Items available somewhere? In the question
[Getting someone's Steam inventory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393099/getting-someones-steam-inventory/17679641#17679641)
Andy very nicely explains how to get Steam inventory content. I am looking for something similar, but not limited by user inventory.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen an official Valve API for available trading cards at this point. However, the owners of [ScrapBank.me](http://scrapbank.me/) have a [public API](http://scrapbank.me/api/) that contains a list of all of the cards their bots have seen. (As of this post on Aug. 1, 2014, that is 8060 unique cards)

You will require an API key, which can be obtained on their API page. After that, it is simple a matter of calling `http://scrapbank.me/api/GetMarketPrices/v1/prices.json?key=<YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY>`. Replace `<YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY>` with the key obtained from your API page.

The result returned is similar to this:

```
{
    "result":{
        "success":1,
        "num_cards_tracked":8060,
        "game":{
            "Steam Summer Getaway":{
                "Chivalry Medieval Warfare":{
                    "type":"Steam Summer Getaway Trading Card",
                    "price":{
                        "usd":0.09,
                        "refined":0.33
                    }
                },
                "Reus":{
                    "type":"Steam Summer Getaway Trading Card",
                    "price":{
                        "usd":0.08,
                        "refined":0.33
                    }
                },
                "Dead Island Riptide":{
                    "type":"Steam Summer Getaway Trading Card",
                    "price":{
                        "usd":0.08,
                        "refined":0.33
                    }
                }
           }
      }
}
```

It is worth noting that new cards will not appear in this API until the ScrapBank.me bots have seen such a card. It is also important to realize that the results for your API call are cached for an hour, so repeated calls to the API will return the same data for an hour even if new cards are added in the mean time.

Comment: scrapbank.me is down at the time of this comment. are there any alternative sites that provide info like this?