# Getting Steam Player's Inventory List (DOTA 2)

Tags: api, steam, inventory

I read some answers from other pages and found http://steamcommunity.com/profiles//inventory/json/570/2 is how I can get the list of the player's inventory. After I went to that address, a lot of data came up. However, the problem is that the data is not presented properly. I got something like this.

> {"success":true,"rgInventory":{"7905269096":{"id":"7905269096","classid":"771158876","instanceid":"782509058","amount":"1","pos":1},"7832200468":{"id":"7832200468","classid":"626495772","instanceid":"1463199080","amount":"1","pos":2},"7832199378":{"id":"7832199378","classid":"626495770","instanceid":"1463199082","amount":"1","pos":3},"7832197795":{"id":"7832197795","classid":"626495773","instanceid":"1463199083","amount":"1","pos":4},"7832127932":{"id":"7832127932","classid":"771156290","instanceid":"1463199085","amount":"1","pos":5},"7832128369":{"id":"7832128369","classid":"626495771","instanceid":"1463199086","amount":"1","pos":6},"7832128042":{"id":"7832128042","classid":"466386035","instanceid":"1463199087","amount":"1","pos":7},"7830087148":{"id":"7830087148","classid":"536091705","instanceid":"1463199088","amount":"1","pos":8},"7822471023":{"id":"7822471023","classid":"771179852","instanceid":"782509058","amount":"1","pos":9},"7797472279":{"id":"7797472279","classid":"771410455","instanceid":"782509058","amount":"1","pos":10},"7782683766":{"id":"7782683766","classid":"771181072","instanceid":"782509058","amount":"1","pos":11},"7631976019":{"id":"7631976019","classid":"771157018","instanceid":"782509058","amount":"1","pos":12}},"rgCurrency":[],"rgDescriptions":{"771158876_782509058":{"appid":"570","classid":"771158876","instanceid":"782509058","icon_url":"W_I_5GLm4wPcv9jJQ7z7tz_l_0sEIYUhRfbF4arNQkgGQGKd3kMuVpMgCwRZrh6GdUmV2uVefqzZAxsqDpH8eVO4Nb2CyAaiWsVUbt1mBngc3Zm32FdEXSSFBuQVD4Z97J3LgwOxDlDHfjc9z40ChfLKg86GW_CBqRXhIgJ1zaQ3WkhKx3uK","icon_url_large":"W_I_5GLm4wPcv9jJQ7z7tz_l_0sEIYUhRfbF4arNQkgGQGKd3kMuVpMgCwRZrh6GdUmV2uVefqzZAxsqDpH8eVO4Nb2CyAaiWsVUbt1mBngc3Zm32CZOBWOAUKgdCoUqtJKW0Q7rCFKTLTVowoQBhPHGhMOGCK_YrRq1JVAm2rA7CM1GhVgPNerBnXLi","icon_drag_url":"","name":"Ogre's
>   Caustic Steel Choppers","market_hash_name":"Ogre's Caustic Steel
>   Choppers","market_name":"Ogre's Caustic Steel
>   Choppers","name_color":"D2D2D2","background_color":"","type":"Uncommon
>   Swords","tradable":0,"marketable":0,"commodity":0,"market_tradable_restriction":"7","market_marketable_restriction":"7","descriptions":[{"type":"html","value":"Used
>   By: Alchemist"}

Is there any way to make it more neater so I can read the data? Or can anyone give me any ideas about how to process these data? Thanks heaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data is in JSON format(http://www.json.org/). It is suited to be consumed by applications. So you should write a little program that will read this data, parse it and query more elements. For example (just guessing here) that there an API where you can get an item by its ID (something like http://steamcommunity.com/items/7832200468).

The output of this program could be a list (text or HTML) of items with their names, values, rarity, etc

Edit: also this: [Getting someone's Steam inventory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393099/getting-someones-steam-inventory?rq=1)