# How do I load Steam (CS:GO in particular) inventory into my website?

Tags: javascript, php, json, steam

I am new to coding, but I am passionate about my project and coding in general. I have been searching everywhere on how to load the CS:GO inventory items as soon as the user of my website clicks on the "Load inventory" button, but all I find is some links people share (which they use to get info about the items from the inventory), but it is no useful to me since I have no idea what to do with it. I would really appreciate it if you could explain what do I do to make this happen (basically from the scratch). I have the Steam login feature on my website already, all I need is the inventory thing.

I hope you can understand what I am trying to say.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think its answered  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393099/getting-someones-steam-inventory) already

Comment: I already read that post as well, but I could not gain anything from it. It does not say what to do with that link (inventory path or something) and how to start the code. Perhaps I just need a less complicated answer.