# Steam Trading Cards: What endpoint to use for own inventory

Tags: json, steam, steam-web-api

As the title says and in short: I want to get the count of cards I have for a given game.

I've seen [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17679641/1519058) but I don't want to see all the inventory (no pagination needed), instead I want to get data of a specific AppID.

`https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<xxxx>/inventory/json/491080/2` seems not to be working as it returns `{"success":false}`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no such endpoint - you'll need to fetch `753/2` and count them one by one.

Trading cards are part of your Steam inventory (AppID code 753) and not game inventory. For example, TF2 cards are placed inside your Steam inventory (753) while the actual in-game items are inside TF2 inventory (440).

Another possibility would be to crawl `http://steamcommunity.com/my/badges` and get the numbers from there. This is what many automated scripts do.

Comment: There's no count of cards displayed in `http://steamcommunity.com/my/badges`, or is there ? or did you mean crawl that page then each badge page... Oh gosh, that would be awful xD

Comment: Yep. Loading `753/2` inventory is probably your best bet.