# Getting inventory contexts of Steam users

Tags: reverse-engineering, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

A [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393099/getting-someones-steam-inventory/17679641) explains how to retrieve a user's public inventory

```
http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<PROFILEID>/inventory/json/<APPID>/<CONTEXTID>
```

I read that context ID must be set as 2 to find items for most games, but this is not always the case. Is there any official API to find a user's inventory contexts? [steamapis.com already has a paid API](https://steamapis.com/docs/steam#profile) which performs this task:

```
{
    "steamID": {
        "universe": 1,
        "type": 1,
        "instance": 1,
        "accountid": 78261062
    },
    "name": "PEPZ",
    "onlineState": "online",
    "stateMessage": "Online",
    "privacyState": "public",
    "visibilityState": "3",
    "avatarHash": "5b702b331ddeb928225ad562a3e729aecd191b9a",
    "vacBanned": false,
    "tradeBanState": "None",
    "isLimitedAccount": false,
    "customURL": "pepzwee",
    "memberSince": "2011-02-21T22:00:00.000Z",
    "location": "Estonia",
    "realName": "SteamApis.com Developer",
    "summary": "",
    "groups": [
        {
            "universe": 1,
            "type": 7,
            "instance": 0,
            "accountid": 28077004
        },
        ...
    ],
    "primaryGroup": {
        "universe": 1,
        "type": 7,
        "instance": 0,
        "accountid": 28077004
    },
    "contexts": {
        "440": {
            "appid": 440,
            "name": "Team Fortress 2",
            "icon": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/440/e3f595a92552da3d664ad00277fad2107345f743.jpg",
            "link": "http://steamcommunity.com/app/440",
            "asset_count": 11,
            "inventory_logo": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/440/e613d1d46de26ea755105b898cc8830d305353f3.png",
            "trade_permissions": "FULL",
            "load_failed": 0,
            "rgContexts": {
                "2": {
                    "asset_count": 11,
                    "id": "2",
                    "name": "Backpack"
                }
            }
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Where **"rgContexts"** contains inventory context for each game.

Answer (score 2):

I found out with some inspect element work, that there is a script tag available with the exact information you need. This is an example of my profile:

```js
var g_rgWalletInfo = {"success":false};
var g_bInventoryIsInModalDialog = false;
var g_bIsInMarketplace = false;

UserYou.SetSteamId( '76561199033382814' );

    var g_rgAppContextData = {"753":{"appid":753,"name":"Steam","icon":"https:\/\/cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/753\/135dc1ac1cd9763dfc8ad52f4e880d2ac058a36c.jpg","link":"https:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/app\/753","asset_count":303,"inventory_logo":"https:\/\/cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/753\/db8ca9e130b7b37685ab2229bf5a288aefc3f0fa.png","trade_permissions":"FULL","load_failed":0,"store_vetted":"1","rgContexts":{"6":{"asset_count":303,"id":"6","name":"Community"}}},"730":{"appid":730,"name":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive","icon":"https:\/\/cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/730\/69f7ebe2735c366c65c0b33dae00e12dc40edbe4.jpg","link":"https:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/app\/730","asset_count":61,"inventory_logo":"https:\/\/cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/730\/3ab6e87a04994b900881f694284a75150e640536.png","trade_permissions":"FULL","load_failed":0,"store_vetted":"1","rgContexts":{"2":{"asset_count":61,"id":"2","name":"Backpack"}}}};
        var g_strInventoryLoadURL = 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/stoplookingatmyid/inventory/json/';
    $J( function() {
        UserYou.LoadContexts( g_rgAppContextData );
    } );

$J( function() {
    var bHasPendingGifts = false;
    InitInventoryPage( bHasPendingGifts, -1, false );
});
var g_bInClient = false;
var g_bInChinaRealm =  false;
var g_bViewingOwnProfile = false;
var g_bMarketAllowed = false;
var g_strLanguage = 'english';
var g_strCountryCode = "US";
var g_strProfileURL = 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/stoplookingatmyid';
```

Some of this data is junk, but `g_rgAppContextData` is exactly what you need in JSON format, and it just needs to be parsed if your programming language of choice. In this example, 753 is the app id of `Steam`, with 6 being the context id, and 730 is `CSGO'S` app id, with 2 as the context id. with  This data won't be present if the user has a private steam inventory.