# How I can load all Steam inventory?

Tags: node.js, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

Actually, I found a lot [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393099/getting-someones-steam-inventory) how load Steam inventory, but any answer how to load all inventory. The problem is to get inventory we need know appID `http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<PROFILEID>/inventory/json/<APPID>/<CONTEXTID>`
But I don't want to make a few millions request to get my 50 items because idk which items appIds in my inventory.