# Steam API - Can't get the users inventory - PHP

Tags: php, json, steam, steam-web-api

I'm messing around and creating a website that uses Steam API to log in.
I'm currently trying to load the users inventory into the website without any greater success and can't find the problem.
If I open the link normally in a web browser it works without any problems.

I have tried multiple different urls without success.

Here's an example of the code:

```
<?php

// Replace STEAM_ID with the Steam ID of the player whose inventory you want to retrieve
$steamid = "STEAM_ID";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/$steamid/inventory/json/730/2");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');

// Execute the cURL request and fetch the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo $response;
// Close the cURL session
curl_close($ch);

$response_data = json_decode($response, true);
$inventory = $response_data['rgDescriptions'];
print_r($inventory);

echo "HTTP status code $http_code\n";
```

Output: {"success":false,"Error":"Unsupported request"}Error: HTTP status code 403

I have also googled and tried different solutions without any different outcome sadly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting someone's Steam inventory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393099/getting-someones-steam-inventory)

Comment: Sadly not, same problem

Comment: file_get_contents() may not be right command for this. Use curl instead.

Comment: Please give more debugging information about your problem. What is the request answer? How are the headers?

Comment: While using curl I got the following Error: HTTP status code 403.

Comment: Please update your code. 403 is Access forbidden.

Comment: Code is updated to what I'm using and getting error 403

Comment: I've tested the code. Works, but there is a cloudflare protection on the server site to prevent grabbing. So you need to obtain a API key to use it properly. https://steamcommunity.com/dev

Comment: sorry for this dumb question, not really an expert in this area.. I do have an API-key, where do I enter it to get it to work?

Comment: Just read the link from above. `All API calls take the form http://api.steampowered.com/<interface name>/<method name>/v<version>/?key=<api key>&format=<format>`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using this endpoint as my url and it worked. Maybe try implementing this in your code to see if you get a response

[https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/{}/730/2](https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/%7B%7D/730/2)